# Activerecord, calculate average percentage for multiple value of grouped value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm try to save some precious millisecond in a query.

I have a stats table and I'm calculating the average value of some records grouped by a key

```
Activity.group(:company_id).average(:completed_courses)
```

Everything is ok, but I need also the average on other columns of the same table (`:readed_news, :logins, etc`)

Is there a way to get all the averages with a single query?

I'm using Postgres

Comment: Couldn't you just fetch the data you need and put it in a hash and do the calculations afterwards?

Comment: It's a huge table with a log of record...

Comment: try to use scopes or class methods on you model!

Answer (score 2):

You can write select.

```
Activity.group(:company_id)
        .select('AVG(completed_courses) as avg_completed_courses, 
                 AVG(readed_news) as avg_readed_news, 
                 AVG(logins) as avg_logins')
```

Also, you can write method for generating select expression:

```
def select_exp(attrs)
  attrs.sum { |attr| ("AVG(#{attr}) as avg_#{attr},") }.chop
end 

Activity.group(:company_id)
        .select select_exp(%w(completed_courses readed_news logins))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single field on `average` method but you can do this

```
activities = Activity.group(:company_id)

completed_courses = activities.average(:completed_courses)

readed_news = activities.average(:readed_news)
etc..
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you try it?
`activities = Activity.group(:company_id)` 
It will not work because it's not a relation.

Answer (score 0):

Use scopes or class methods on you model:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.average_company
      group(:company_id).average(:completed_courses)
    end

    self.average_readed_news
      group(:readed_news).average(:completed_courses)
    end
end
```

then call:

```
Activity.average_company
Actvitity.average_readed_news
```

You could then try to merge scopes

```
Activity.average_company.merge(Activity.average_readed_news)
```

Look at the documentation here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html